# Capture mouse events for HTML option element on IE

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, internet-explorer, html-select

For Internet Explorer only it seems that the target (srcElement) of clicks, mousedowns, mouseups, mouseovers, etc. on `<select />` elements will not be tied to the `<option />` element.

Given the following HTML:

```html
<select id="madness">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="2">Three</option>
</select>
```

and this basic jQuery event handler:

```
$("#madness").mousedown(function(e){
   alert(e.target.value); //jQuery pushes srcElement into the target for us here
});
```

The object that is in `e.target` or `e.srcElement` is always equal to the `<select />` and not the `<option />`.

I decided to get creative and try to use `document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY)` and that returns the `<select />` element as well.

That brings the question, is there any way to determine the `<option />` inside of a `<select />` via event arguments,coordinates, or anything else?  I'm aware that I can fake this out with a scrollable div of checkboxes.  For the purposes of this question, I'd like any solutions which can use the native select element.

Comment: I don't *think* Chrome supports events originating from `<option>` elements either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put simply there are no solutions that use the native select element.

Comment: The IE Team don't seem to think so: "In IE7 however, we re-implemented the <SELECT> element to make IE7 more standards-compliant. This new version *does not use any Shell controls any more*. In fact, *it is implemented totally through the MSHTML framework*, including styling, UI interaction, and rendering" - http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx (emphasis added)

Comment: @NickFitz:  Point taken, misleading text removed.  However it seems unlikely they would have started from scratch. I can see the sense of bring it inside MSHTML since it eliminates some DLL-HELL.

Comment: It's a little disappointing, but this was where I suspecting this was going.  I just wanted to see if there were other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("#madness").val()
```

To get the value of the selected <option />.

Comment: On mousedown and hover events, there is no selected option.

Comment: Are you trying to just select the <option> into a jquery object? You can do $("#madness").children() to get all the <option> values and then you can use a $.each() to loop through them all.

Comment: No, I'm actually trying to get only the option underneath the mouse.